# Reset jQuery Validation (GeekTantra plugin)

Tags: jquery

Hi guys
I'm using the jQuery Validation plugin by GeekTantra [link](http://www.geektantra.com/2009/09/jquery-live-form-validation/) with some custom variations.

I would like to find out if there is a way to reset the error checking by clicking a certain element (i.e. a div class="reset" or a tab with a specific class).

I have 2 forms in the same page, but only one showing at any given time (one under each tab). If a user submits Form1 and errors appear, he has an option to try another method by selecting the second tab, which reveals Form2. All working fine so far, but if he clicks again on the first tab, the errors are still showing.

What I would like to achieve is that if you click on any Tab, all validation is completely reset for all forms, so no more errors are showing and everything related to jQuery validation starts from scratch. Is that possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In your tab change function you can write following piece of code,

```
document.forms['a123'].reset();
```

as well as hide your error divs/spans.

```
$(".error").hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately this is not working. I do not want to hide the error messages, because I need to run validation again. The validation process needs to be completely reset (as if I was to refresh the page), so it's ready to be triggered again.